# how to add MDCard in ScrollView in KivyMD?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I am new to KivyMD and I have this doubt. How to add an MDCard in ScrollView, just like how we do with lists. Is it possible to do that or not. I referred to a lot of online solutions and websites but none of the questions are related to my question. Please somebody help

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, I came across this while searching for some other answer, I will leave the solution here just in case anyone needs it.

MDCards as of now can't be added to ScrollView as it is.

To make a scrollable list of cards, you will have to define a custom class, study the following code:

```
<CardItem@RelativeLayout>
    size_hint_y: None
    height: '150dp'
    radius: 50
    # for use in ScrollView

    MDCard:
        size_hint: .9, .9
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
        Image:
            source: 'images/sample1.png'
        # you can make these cards as complex as you like
```

Now

```
ScrollView:
    MDList:
        CardItem
        CardItem:
            size_hint: .9, .9
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
            Image:
                source: 'images/sample2.png'
```

Note that, the properties defined can be overwritten and new properties can be added as well.

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: You can also use elevations and all other properties with above method